# Solr: what is the impact of number of field elements on the index/search performance?

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

What is the impact of number of field elements on the index/search performance?

We have the following document structure with some documents having upto 400 field elements. 
We have seen the solr server CPU usage go up and have not isolated the issue to the increase # of elements but wondering if anybody did `any analysis on the Solr performance vs # of field elements.`

We are using a single Solr server for both indexing and also reads, with auto-commit enabled.

```
<add>
    <doc>
        <field name="id">User 4990</field>
        <field name="type">User</field>
        <field name="type">ActiveRecord::Base</field>
        <field name="class_name">User</field>
        <field name="id_i">4990</field>
        <field name="login_s">someuser</field>
        <field name="first_name_s">some</field>
        <field name="last_name_s">user</field>
        <field name="email_s">someuser@somecompany.com</field>
        <field name="department_s">department-psg</field>
        <field name="activated_b">true</field>
        <field name="private_profile_b">false</field>
        <field name="deleted_b">false</field>
        <field name="followers_im">4834</field>
        <field name="followers_im">4965</field>
        <field name="followers_im">3</field>
        <field name="followers_im">4291</field>

        ...
        ...
        ..
        <field
            ..
        <**400** such fields

    ..
    </doc>
</add>
```

Solr version: 3.6.1, Java 6 on Cent OS 5.6

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you are searching over all fields and what operators you are using, the size of the data stored in the fields, how the fields are defined in the schema and whether you only search over the fields or retrieve data from them to display.

In general searching is quite fast, in my schema I have ~100 fields. However, there are inefficient queries which can slow things down. Please refer to [the solr performance wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) for more details.

From my own experience I can tell you that highlighting is affected strongly by the number of fields that you highlight on, because it runs over each field of each result document i.e. high number of fields gives you quadratic complexity in practice.